# Hide parts of a line from LaTeX output

Tags: agda, literate-programming

Is there a way to hide parts of a line from the LaTeX output?

For whole lines, this works:

```
\begin{code}
foo : Tm Γ t
\end{code}
\begin{code}[hide]
foo = someHiddenDefinitionOfFoo
\end{code}
```

but what if I want to hide parts of a line, e.g. parts of a type signature? For example, suppose I have this Agda signature:

```
sub-⊢*⊇ : ∀ {Γ Δ Θ t} (σ : Γ ⊢* Δ) (Δ⊇Θ : Δ ⊇ Θ) (e : Tm Θ t) →
  sub (σ ⊢*⊇ Δ⊇Θ) e ≡ sub σ (ren Δ⊇Θ e)
```

but I'd like it to look like this in the LaTeX output:

```
sub-⊢*⊇ : ∀ σ Δ⊇Θ e → sub (σ ⊢*⊇ Δ⊇Θ) e ≡ sub σ (ren Δ⊇Θ e)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: in your example, you are not just hiding parts, you are simplifying the signature, which is not valid code, right?.

Comment: @white_wolf: Yes, correct. But , it could be done purely syntactically by just hiding the line fragments  `{Γ Δ Θ t} (`, `: Γ ⊢* Δ) (`, `: Δ ⊇ Θ) (` and `: Tm Θ t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust approach for doing this kind of thing is to use
anonymous modules for the arguments you want to hide:

```
sub-⊢*⊇ : ∀ {Γ Δ Θ t} (σ : Γ ⊢* Δ) (Δ⊇Θ : Δ ⊇ Θ) (e : Tm Θ t) →
  sub (σ ⊢*⊇ Δ⊇Θ) e ≡ sub σ (ren Δ⊇Θ e)
```

thus becomes

```
module _ {Γ Δ Θ t} where

 sub-⊢*⊇ : (σ : Γ ⊢* Δ) (Δ⊇Θ : Δ ⊇ Θ) (e : Tm Θ t) →
   sub (σ ⊢*⊇ Δ⊇Θ) e ≡ sub σ (ren Δ⊇Θ e)
```

If you're willing to use a very basic `sed` script to postprocess the LaTeX file to erase simple `{var}` arguments, you should be able to get your intended goal with something like:

```
module _ {Γ Δ Θ t} where

 sub-⊢*⊇ : ∀ σ Δ⊇Θ e → sub {Γ} (σ ⊢*⊇ Δ⊇Θ) e ≡ sub σ (ren {Δ} {Θ} Δ⊇Θ e)
```

Comment: I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2946) asking for this to be automated

Answer (score -3):

The `verbatim` package provides a `comment` environment.

```
\begin{comment}
    Something not taken into account
\end{comment}
```

Comment: But how would I add this to the middle of my Agda program, inline, inside a `code` block?

Comment: I must say I don't know if this is possible, has to be tested. However, I don't think there is a simple way to do as you want, except using classical comment "%".

Comment: How is the verbatim package relevant to generating latex using literate agda and the latex backend?